# JavaScript: Using HTML files to make components?

Tags: javascript, html, components

Is there a way to make files like `navbar.html` and then using JavaScript to use files like these as components? For example, Let's say I have a file called `imageCarousel.html` and I have to use this file in many different HTML files so how can I make a JavaScript file that has a function that takes in the class of where I want to display the HTML file's code, and then the path of the HTML file and then also how can I use that JavaScript file in other JavaScript files?

**I have searched many different places and I can clearly state that there is no other place for this exact question. And I am asking this question after doing all the research.**

**Also I don't want to use any library here like react etc.**

Thanks for reading this query!

Comment: Why do you want to use dot html extension if you need this type of functionality? If you don't have to stick to html extension, then there are multiple ways to achieve what you are saying.

Comment: @JayendraSharan I am open to your answer. Just tell me how can I achieve this functionality. Thanks!

Comment: You are thinking about code reusability like React , but I think there is not a way to do this according to your query, you will have to copy the code of one HTML file into another.

Comment: If you want to handle everything by yourself, you can create JavaScript files with a function that returns HTML template. Or you can use `ejs` or handlebars or any other template engine. You can also use React :)

Comment: @JayendraSharan how can I use ejs without node here?

Comment: See: if you want to split your code into multiple files, you would want to use some kind of bundler or package creator. For this you need `node`. To support the development. In actual application, once you are done with dev..you don't need node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your templates using JS functions. As explained in the comment, you would need some kind of development environment to write your code into multiple file and then organise them.

If you don't want to this...Here is what you can do.

```
index.html

<script src="/path/to/Navigation.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/index.js"></script>
```

```
in Navigation.js

function Navbar (text) {
  return `
    <nav class='navbar'>
      <h1>Hello Template</h1>
      <a href="www.google.com">Go To Google</a>
      <h3>${text}</h3>
    </nav>
  `;
};
```

```
in index.js
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = Navbar("Hello from template");
```

See this codesandbox for example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-mccarthy-t6msj?file=/index.html

PS: This is a bad practice though, and it will get complicated as your application grows. Because the sequence of imported files will matter. Consider them as depedencies. In this case, `index.js` needs `Navigation.js` and this chain will grow with as many as components and scripts you add.

So I would suggest you to explore the module building library if you want to build an application. If you are just trying to learn...then I guess this will help.

Comment: How did you get that Navbar function in the index.js file? Is it because of the script tag before?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer :)

Comment: I feel your answer is closest to what I want thanks!

Comment: And you unaccepted my answer..ha ha.. :)

Comment: Yea I accepted your answer first but I accepted another after as well that's why maybe sorry

Comment: No worries - also, if you are learning JS, you can connect with me on discord. I'll try to reply to the queries as much as I can. my id: jayendrasharan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237346/discussion-between-code-fingers-and-jayendra-sharan).

Answer (score 1):

With JS projects normally use modules in many `.js` files, not html. For import other modules can use `import something from './file.js` or `const module = require('./someFile.js')`.

For bundle all files together and generate HTML + JS static files need to use **bundlers**. Bundlers also can transpile newer JS syntax for support older browsers.

Most used bundler is [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), can look at `rollup`, `parcel` or `esbuild` too.

Have many [tutorials how to use webpack](https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/tutorial-how-to-build-a-webpack-app-with-vanilla-js-or-react-72ca2cc7e14)

UPD. Can also look into [RequireJS](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage), but it's old approach.

Comment: But will it not take me a lot of time to learn it first? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: WIll take time, but if you wanna reuse some modules across many modules/pages will need to use some tools.

Comment: Okay, understandable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with a js library like react.js ! with it you can create a js component and call it on other js files! if you dont want to use react that i dont know if its possible with pure js!

Comment: I am sorry but I don't want to use react here for some reason. Can you pls edit your answer? Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadHTML(url){
    return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        fetch(url).then(r=>r.text()).then(r=>{
            var html = document.createElement("div")
            html.innerHTML = r
            res(html.querySelector("*"))
        })            
    })
}

loadHTML("scrollImageChange.html").then(r=>{
    document.body.append(r)
})
```

**Note:** wrap all html markup inside one root element to have it working properly otherwise this function will return only first child

Answer (score 0):

I think you can parse that HTML file to make it a DOM object and then you can manipulate it as you like. Just like a JS component.

For example, use an HTTP call to fetch the HTML file as string and then use it with [DOMParser()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)
To create a DOM object.